# Restore Job in MSSQL failing

Tags: sql-server, backup, restore, jobs

The backup job of being completed, however, the restoring job is failing.

//EDIT

I am trying to perform logshipping

Getting the following errors:

```
Date        10/25/2023 4:45:00 PM
Log     Job History (LSRestore)
Step ID     1
Server      REPORTING
Job Name        LSRestore
Step Name       Log shipping restore log job step.
Duration        00:00:35
Sql Severity    0
Sql Message ID  0
Operator Emailed    
Operator Net sent   
Operator Paged  
Retries Attempted   0
Message
2023-10-25 16:45:35.14  Found first log backup file to restore. Secondary CMS_CUSTOMER_NEW: 'CUSTOMERNEW', File: '\\REPORTING\LogShipping\CUSTOMERNEW.trn'
2023-10-25 16:45:35.15  *** Error: Could not apply log backup file '\\REPORTING\LogShipping\CUSTOMERNEW.trn' to secondary database 'CUSTOMERNEW'.(Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.LogShipping) ***
2023-10-25 16:45:35.15  *** Error: This backup set cannot be applied because it is on a recovery path that is inconsistent with the database. The recovery path is the sequence of data and log backups that have brought the database to a particular recovery point. Find a compatible backup to restore, or restore the rest of the database to match a recovery point within this backup set, which will restore the database to a different point in time.  For more information about recovery paths, see SQL Server Books Online.
RESTORE LOG is terminating abnormally.(.Net SqlClient Data Provider) ***
2023-10-25 16:45:35.21  *** Error: The log backup file '\\REPORTING\LogShipping\CUSTOMERNEW.trn' was verified but could not be applied to secondary database 'CUSTOMERNEW'.(Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.LogShipping) ***
2023-10-25 16:45:35.21  Deleting old log backup files. Primary Database: 'CUSTOMERNEW'
```

Comment: @vonPryz, yes I am trying log shipping

Comment: Looks like you're trying to restore logs to a backup that isn't consistent with those logs. Probably need to reset and restart.

Comment: thanks, @DanCo!